# How to display a calendar in vertical format?

Tags: perl

I need to display a calendar in a vertical format; how can I get this format? I tried some sample perl scripts.

Script:

```
  use strict;
  use Calendar::Simple;

  my @months = qw(January February March April May June July August
                  September October November December);

  my $mon = shift;
  my $yr  = shift;

  my @month = calendar($mon, $yr);

  print "\n$months[$mon -1] $yr\n\n";
  print "Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa\n";
  foreach (@month) {
    print map { $_ ? sprintf "%2d ", $_ : '   ' } @$_;
    print "\n";
  }
```

It can be executed as normal calendar as horizontal format; how can I change to vertical format...

Need output as:

```
sun   1 5 6   
mon  2 3
wed ...
thu ...
fri ...
stu ...
```

How I do this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you just want weekdays inserted before whitespaces,

UPDATE: added @month2 which transforms @month

```
# ...
my @month = calendar($mon, $yr);
my @month2 = map {
  my $v=$_;
  [ map $_->[$v], @month ]
} 0..6;

my @wd = qw(Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa);
for my $i (0 .. $#month2) {

  my $el = $month2[$i];
  print $wd[$i], map {
    $_ ? sprintf("%2d ", $_) : "   ";
  }
  @$el;
  print "\n";
}
```